# cannot set background color of UITableViewCell in iOS6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-simulator

I started testing my app under simulator, because I don't have any iOS 6 device and stumbled upon weird problem. I cannot set backgroundColor property of UITableViewCell. If I st this:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

it is working only for iOS 6, when I use this:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

or this

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

it is working only for iOS7.

When I use both `cell.contentView` and `cell.backgroundColor` it's working for both iOS... shouldn't it be one answer for such a 'easy' property? Or maybe it's some simulator bug?

UPDATE:
If it changes anything in the same tableview and cells I cannot set `accessoryType` neither via StoryBoard nor code...

UPDATE2: for some reason setting tableview style to plain deleted all my changes, but grouped showed as expected...

Answer (score 19):

In iOS6 you need to change the cell's backgroundColor in willDisplayCell.
This works in iOS7 as well, precluding the need for version-specific code.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in iOS 7. For iOS 6, I needed to set the backgroundColor in both `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCell` methods. If not (if set only in willDisplayCell), when adding a new row, the `willDisplayCell` will only be activated for the newly displayed cell, but the other still-visible cells background color will be reset.

Comment: it works great,  it should be accepted as true answer.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see the problem in setting the background for the contentView AND directly to the cell. iOS 7 has change a lot this class. If you need to be compatible with old systems then you need to do this type of things.

So yes, you should use both:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor
cell.backgroundColor
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to change the cell's backgroundView color not the backgroundColor.

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.backgroundView = myView;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set (assuming you use standard cell):

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

...then you just have to use:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

iOS 6 seems to copy table's background color to textLabel.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code:

```
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```